# Atomic swap map pointer cause program stuck

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "sync/atomic"
   "unsafe"
)



func main(){
   old := make(map[string]string)
   new := make(map[string]string)
   new["hello"] = "apple"
   fmt.Println("start swap")
   atomic.SwapPointer((*unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(&old)), unsafe.Pointer(&new))
   fmt.Println("end swap")

   // pending here, don't stop
   fmt.Println(old)
   fmt.Println("end print old")

}
```

I want a **lock-free** way to update old map with new map because of the old map will be concurrent read at the most of the time. 
if I use a rwlock, there will have serious **performance** penalty.
so I choose Golang atomic package to implement this, but the line 
**fmt.Println(old)**, the program is stuck here, could somebody give some advice.

Comment: Go's `sync/atomic` package is not well defined and can misbehave in unexpected ways. It's not documented except for requiring 'great care'. Here's a [discussion on a mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/0uPDCRiBWqc) where they're still trying to decide what it should do so it can be documented.

Long story short, don't use 'sync/atomic'. Measure the performance using rwlock, improve where possible, only then go into less documented/unsafe territory.

Comment: Your use of unsafe is wrong, and you're corrupting the memory. The perceived benefits of using unsafe for performance purposes many times results in unexpected bugs because you're relying on runtime-specific features and underlying representations, which change from release to release. Also, the way you're trying to swap maps does not look useful. That will only protect the variables referencing the map, not the map itself. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "I want a lock-free way ..." There is no "I want" in Go.

Comment: "if I use a rwlock, there will have serious performance penalty." Until you benchmarked it this is at most a hypothesis. (Others might call it a premature optimisation).

Comment: Depending on what you really are trying to do experimenting with sync.Map might be useful.

Comment: Note that the language is called "Go" and golang.org is the website.

Answer (score 2):

The function `atomic.SwapPointer` does not do what you want / need.  As [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#SwapPointer) says, this is roughly equivalent to:

```
old = *addr
*addr = new
return old
```

(except that the write to `*addr` and read-back from `*addr` are done atomically).  What you wanted was, I think, the atomic equivalent of:

```
*old, *new = *new, *old
```

(and no useful return value).  This operation simply does not exist in the `sync` package.  If it did, you could swap the two internal map pointers, but you'd still be treading in dangerous (might-break-in-future-compilers) waters, as multiple commenters noted.

Consider using [`sync.Map`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map) instead.  It provides a somewhat-concurrency-safe map with internal (per entry) locking that is optimized for two use cases, as described in the linked package documentation.  If your use case is one of these two, it may provide what you need.

---

Just for illustration (don't do this! it's silly, you could just write `*old, *new = *new, *old` in `swap`)... [A non-atomic swap of old and new *can* be achieved using `atomic.SwapPointer`](https://play.golang.org/p/n0C5fbv3VKI):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync/atomic"
    "unsafe"
)

func read(p unsafe.Pointer) unsafe.Pointer {
    return *(*unsafe.Pointer)(p)
}

func swap(old *map[string]string, new *map[string]string) {
    p := atomic.SwapPointer((*unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(old)), read(unsafe.Pointer(new)))
    _ = atomic.SwapPointer((*unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(new)), p)
}

func main() {
    old := map[string]string{"old": "old"}
    new := map[string]string{"hello": "apple", "new": "new"}
    fmt.Println("before: old =", old, "new =", new)
    // fmt.Println("before: old:", read(unsafe.Pointer(&old)), "new:", read(unsafe.Pointer(&new)))
    swap(&old, &new)
    // fmt.Println("after: old:", read(unsafe.Pointer(&old)), "new:", read(unsafe.Pointer(&new)))
    fmt.Println("after: old =", old, "new =", new)
}
```

Uncomment the commented-out lines to see more details.   Of course, calling two separate `atomic.SwapPointer` operations is not atomic: there is a moment when both map variables view the new map, until the second swap makes the `old` variable view the old map.  I *think* the `unsafe.Pointer` variable `p` preserves the old map against GC until we get it stored back into `old`, but I am not at all sure about this (that's one of the darker corners of Go).

Again: don't do this.  If measurement suggests it helps, try `sync.Map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since go 1.17, there is a [atomic.Value.Swap](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Value.Swap) method that I believe does what you want.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync/atomic"
)

func main() {
    var old atomic.Value
    old.Store(make(map[string]string))
    new := make(map[string]string)
    new["hello"] = "apple"
    fmt.Println("start swap")
    new = old.Swap(new).(map[string]string)
    fmt.Println("end swap")

    fmt.Println(old)
    fmt.Println("end print old")
    fmt.Println(new)
}
```

That being said, it's not clear from your use case that you actually need access to the old values, and if not, you can just use [atomic.Value.Store](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Value.Store) to update the pointer instead. In fact, there is [a very similar example in the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#example-Value-ReadMostly).

That being said, I agree with the sentiment that you should measure the impact of using `RWLock` and `sync.Map` before reaching for `atomic.Value`.